# http2: server sent GOAWAY and closed the connection; LastStreamID=73, ErrCode=NO_ERROR, debug="" when pushing docker image to private Artifactory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nuxeo

I have a Dockerfile which use [Nuxeo](https://hub.docker.com/_/nuxeo) as a base image.
I can build the file successfully but whenever I tried to push it locally to the private Artifactory it keeps retrying to push some layers and then it stops to show this error:

```
8c02234b8605: Layer already exists 
EOF
```

if I tried to push it using an automated script (for example Jenkins) it takes to much time (around 15 minutes) after that I get this error:

```
http2: server sent GOAWAY and closed the connection; LastStreamID=73, ErrCode=NO_ERROR, debug=""
```

I think I'm getting these errors because of the image size,  is there a way to speed up the pushing process or minimize the image size?

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nuxeo:LTS-2019

USER user_dd
COPY ./nuxeo_studio/ /opt/nuxeo/server/nuxeo-packages/

CMD [ "nuxeoctl", "console" ]
USER 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue has been fixed finally!

apparently, it was because of the cached layers while building the image. some of the layers were retying to be pushed multiple times. so that’s why the server was sending  `GOAWAY and closed the connection`  . I added the  "--no-cashe"  option to the build command and it worked!